# Custom configuration in gradle

Tags: gradle, configuration

I'm defining separate configuration in gradle for jupiter (Junit 5) tests. I have following snippet in the gradle file:

My understanding is jupiterCompile will extend dependencies from testCompile including any dependencies defined for self. In this case my testCompile configuration doesn't have any jupiter dependencies but as jupiterCompile has those sets of dependencies, I expect them to be available. However, if I write testCompile.extendsFrom jupiterCompile it does work which is confusing to me.

```
configurations {
jupiterTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
jupiterTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
jupiterTestCompileOnly.extendsFrom testCompileOnly
}
dependencies {
def jUnitVersion = "5.5.1"
jupiterTestCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter- 
api:${jUnitVersion}")
jupiterTestRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter- 
engine:${jUnitVersion}")
jupiterTestCompileOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter- 
migrationsupport:${jUnitVersion}")
jupiterTestRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage- 
engine:${jUnitVersion}")
}
```

If I have common dependencies defined under testCompile and want jupiterCompile configuration to inherit them, what should be the right configuration?

Comment: *I expect them to be available*: you expect them to be available to what? What are you doing with these additional configurations?

Comment: Additional configuration is for specific dependencies. e.g. jupterTest should only be using dependencies from test AND whatever defined for that configuration like all the above jupiter jars. (jupterCompile extendsFrom testCompile). So, my jupierTest which are my unit tests should only use jupiter jars and not any other dependencies e.g specified for integrationTest.

Comment: OK. But did you configure the test task to use that new configuration rather than using the default ones? That won't happen magically.

Comment: ohh..so it doesn't extend the default test task? Do I need to create new task like "task test (type: Test)"?

Comment: No, that would try to create a new task with the name of the already existing task `test`. But again, why are you creating a separate configuration? What's wrong in having the standard test task using the standard test configurations, and in having JUnit declared in the standard test cofigurations?

Comment: The idea is that test configuration would only have common dependencies required for unit test and integration test. Something like unitTest extends testCompile and integrationTest extends testCompile.